# How to extract protein names from a file using re.search and group() function

Tags: python

I am attempting to extract all of the protein names from a file and save it as a list, however I keep on getting an empty list as my output.
Here is an example of a few of the lines in the file. Please note that the file is basically proteins of different species, I need to extract the name which is indicated by OS= name of species.

```
sp|Q8C025|CHPT1_MOUSE Cholinephosphotransferase 1 OS=Mus musculus GN=Chpt1 PE=1 SV=1
sp|Q9Y6K0|CEPT1_HUMAN Choline/ethanolaminephosphotransferase 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=CEPT1 PE=1 SV=1
sp|O14735|CDIPT_HUMAN CDP-diacylglycerol--inositol 3-phosphatidyltransferase OS=Homo sapiens GN=CDIPT PE=1 SV=1
sp|Q8WUD6|CHPT1_HUMAN Cholinephosphotransferase 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=CHPT1 PE=1 SV=1
sp|P17898|CPT1_YEAST Cholinephosphotransferase 1 OS=Saccharomyces cerevisiae (strain ATCC 204508 / S288c) GN=CPT1 PE=1 SV=3
sp|O80952|PGPS1_ARATH CDP-diacylglycerol--glycerol-3-phosphate 3-phosphatidyltransferase 1, chloroplastic OS=Arabidopsis thaliana GN=PGPS1 PE=1 SV=1
sp|P22140|EPT1_YEAST Choline/ethanolaminephosphotransferase 1 OS=Saccharomyces cerevisiae (strain ATCC 204508 / S288c) GN=EPT1 PE=1 SV=2
```

> The species name in the above example Mus musculus AKA the house mouse. All the sequence names are similar with the 'OS=' indicating the beginning of the species name followed by the genus and the species separated with a space.

Bellow are the instructions for the problem:

> 1. Go through the file protein_names.txt and extract all the species names.
> 2. Combine the genus and species name into a single string separated with a space (e.g "Mus musculus") and be sure to remove any spaces at the start or end of the name.
> 3. Many species are represented by more than one protein. You can include or exclude redundant names - I don't care

This is what I have coded so far:

```
name_file= open("protein_names.txt")
name_file_contents = name_file.readlines()
name_file_2=str(name_file_contents)
protein = r"^OS=(.\n.)$"
search= re.search(protein,name_file_2)
species_names= []

for protein_names in name_file:
    if search:
        search.group()
        species_names.append(search.group())
print(species_names)
```

Receiving an empty list and not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Please provide a more substantial example of the file (even if it's just 3 or 4 lines) and the expected output

Comment: I’ll second what @Ruzihm said. With some more data I should be able to get you a quick answer :) Also, what’s all that stuff before the “OS=“?

Comment: I tried writing an answer but there are just too many things wrong with the code. Please make a [mre] about one specific problem. To start, check whether your regex works by testing it with one string. Then try a list of strings. You might want to read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework".

Comment: To be clear, that regex is very wrong, `str(name_file_contents)` doesn't make any sense, and `re.search` should be inside the loop. Also you want `.group(1)`.

Comment: BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: @  Ruzihm, Alexander Cécile and wjandrea , thank you for looking over my code. First time using python and having difficulty on how to apply some of the functions. I would much appreciate your suggestions and help :)! I have included a few more lines from the file as asked!!!!

Comment: @Lana Please include the expected output as well...

Comment: Good news, I seem to have found a description of the data format! https://www.uniprot.org/help/fasta-headers

Comment: @Ruzihm and  Alexander Cécile, thank you for your help and for providing me with the different code variations as well. Trying to learn how to code for different regular expressions, would be great if you guys could recommend any pdfs or other resources?

Comment: @Lana I love https://regex101.com, I know there are a few other sites similar sites as well. It's how I write any regular expressions I need, I don't know what I would do without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways of accomplishing this, I will keep trying to find a better one. Other users have already given you advice on your code, so I don't have anything to add for now.

For now, here is a straightforward solution. It reads the file lazily so memory use should not be a problem.

```py
import re


org_name_regex = re.compile(r'(?<=OS=)[a-zA-Z0-9 ()/]+(?= )')


def get_file_org_names(file_path, unique=True):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as in_file:
        match_objs = (org_name_regex.search(curr_line) for curr_line in in_file)
        names_lst = (item.group() for item in match_objs if item is not None)
        if unique:
            return set(names_lst)
        else:
            return list(names_lst)


org_names_unq = set(get_file_org_names(protein_file_path, True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each line and use the regular expression `"OS=\\s*(\\S+ \\S+)"` in `re.search`. Check if a match occurred, and if it did, get the group in parenthesis using `group(1)`, then add it to the set of species:

```
import re

species = set()

with open("protein_names.txt") as protein_file:
    for line in protein_file:
        result = re.search("OS=\\s*(\\S+ \\S+)", line)
        if result is not None:
            species.add(result.group(1))

print(species)
```

---

And for fun, here's a version that does most of the work in one line:

```
import re

species = None
with open("protein_names.txt") as protein_file:
    species = set(result.group(1) for result in re.finditer("OS=\\s*(\\S+ \\S+)", protein_file.read()))

print(species)
```

And for extra fun, another ~one-liner that iterates over the file instead of loading it all at once:

```
import re, itertools

species = None
with open("protein_names.txt") as protein_file:
    species = set(result.group(1) for result in itertools.chain(
            *(re.finditer("OS=\\s*(\\S+ \\S+)", line) for line in protein_file)
            ))

print(species)
```

Comment: In your last solution, is there any point in using `finditer` since you're operating on a single line at a time?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile some lines may not contain a match for some reason or another, and `finditer` always returns an iterable regardless of if a match is found or not.

Comment: Ah I see, and then you call `chain` which deals with any empty `match` object iterators. Nice!